# I want /review tool to dismiss flags as "valid but no further action required"

Tags: feature-request, flags, review

From the [flagging tools available to users](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) I sometimes see flagged questions or answers where the flag was submitted ages ago but the problem has since been corrected:

> [image: Already-closed question flagged as duplicate]

In this case, the question has *already* been closed as a duplicate of the suggested URL.

I want something better than **invalid flag**: *I do not agree with the existing flags on this question, they are incorrect and should be ignored.*

The flag was valid. It is just no longer needed. The flagger deserves credit for flagging the post -- **invalid** would deprive the flagger of the corresponding flag weight. I don't need to pile on my own flag -- it's been handled.<sup>1</sup>

Another example can be found in this answer to [Passing values from one jsp page to another jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385483/passing-valus-to-one-jsp-page-to-another-jsp-page/4497487#4497487) -- it was flagged as low quality, minitech fixed it up, and now it is fine. (Terse, perhaps.) No one else should be bothered with this flag again and whoever flagged it should get the corresponding increase in flag weight.

May I have another option when handling flags labeled **this flag was valid but no further action required**?

1: <sub>I didn't cast a delete vote for this specific instance because I believe the wording is different enough from the duplicated question that someone might find the answer through this post.</sub>

Comment: As a cheap workaround, you could flag with a custom message to a mod (indicating this is the case), who has the ability to do just this, we can dismiss the flag as helpful without doing anything (and we usually check the flag times vs edits to make sure that things line up).

Comment: But when was that flag submitted?  Before or after the close?  If before, it should have been silently cleared with some status, it shouldn't have remained.  If after, then well it's clearly invalid now.  If we reward such post-closure flags, then it would be subject to further abuse.

Comment: @Jeff: Pity I didn't gather the specific flagging times for either example. Next example I find I'll be more diligent. Thanks!

Comment: Update: the [low quality flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606) is now automatically removed after a post has been edited -- thus fixing my second example. (I hope this doesn't lead to abuse, but the very low quality flag probably wouldn't be visible to people asking the low quality questions in the first place. Probably fine.)