# /tools/flagged flag removed but post remains

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

The [`/tools/flagged`](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) page included a link to [Broken Java 3D Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087503/broken-java-3d-graphics) with a flag on the [rage-edited second version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9087503/revisions). A user reverted to the original; I voted "invalid flag" because the situation had been handled (see [my feature request for a "dismiss as helpful"-equivalent for us mortals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119191/i-want-review-tool-to-dismiss-flags-as-valid-but-no-further-action-required) for a suggestion on how to improve the situation where the flag has been adequately handled).

However, this question *still* remains in my `/tools/flagged` page, even after several refreshes. When I try to click "invalid flag" on this post with the button, I get the bright-orange-dialog:

> There are no remaining flags on this post.

If there are no remaining flags, please do not show the post in the flagged posts page.

Comment: This has happened to me as well, on Ask Ubuntu ([this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions/183468#183468)). That post ought to be improved, but it should not be removed by a moderator, so I tried to "invalid flag" its automatic "Low answer quality score [88], /questions/how-to-answer shown and skipped" flag. That usually works, but here it did not, and the "There are no remaining flags on this post" message was shown.