# There are no remaining flags on this post

Tags: support, 10k-tools, flags

Today I saw this entry in the flagged posts queue:

[image]

After inspecting the links it was clear that this was just a seasoned StackOverflow user cleaning up some answers. So I tried to flag "invalid flag". Then this box appeared saying

> There are no remaining flags on this post.

And nothing seemed to change.

Can someone help me understand this message and tell me what to do when I see this?

The only (unanswered) question I found on this message is [/tools/flagged flag removed but post remains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120899/tools-flagged-flag-removed-but-post-remains).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That flag was dismissed by me based on the same observation as you state. I suppose I'd dismissed it just after it was loaded and shown to you and just before you tried to dispute it.

If the flag is still being displayed to you, it's probably a caching issue, although I don't believe flags should ever be cached (or at least not aggressively).

Comment: Ah. Should be something like that. Some lag seems to be involved though, because I tried a second time half a minute later or so, with the same result. The entry is gone now by the way.

Comment: So I guess the answer to the question what to do in this situation is: wait a few minutes. Or ignore it altogether, I's probably been taken care of.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: Spot on. I'd forgotten to note that in my answer.