# Option to mark flags as NOT urgent?

Tags: discussion, flags

When going through the /tools page, I often come across "Not an answer" flags on old non-answers, possibly to closed as off topic/not constructive questions.

Now, if I add my NaA flag, it goes up nearer the top of the flag queue as I understand, indicating it would somewhat urgently need to be dealt with. If I don't, it stays, cluttering the page for every 10k+ user for longer.

But deleting a years old non-answer is usually not urgent, even if I think it should definitely be deleted.

So what if there was an option to support the flag but mark it as not urgent on the /tools page that would move such items to a separate "definitely deal with it, but it can wait until you have time" queue and remove it from the 10k+ /tools page (say after two reviewers chose that option)?

Would that make it easier for the moderators or complicate matters more?

Comment: Especially annoying lately because someone's been going through all the old community-wiki answers and looking for downvoted answers and flagged them _all_. Almost all of them were wrong. Sigh.

Comment: Incidentally, I also [want the ability to make flags not bother our moderators at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119191/i-want-review-tool-to-dismiss-flags-as-valid-but-no-further-action-required). :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two factors already working in our favor here.  First, if an "answer" is just a "thanks, that worked" or a "me too, I have the same problem" then it only takes us about 1 second to recognize that and process the flag.  Go ahead and flag these as "not an answer" and we'll take care of them.

The other thing that we have is a sidebar for grouping flags by type.

[image: Flag Breakdown]

Most of us have already learned that "not an answer" flags are quick to process, so we click on that link first and clear those out before looking at the other categories.  If you think a "not an answer" post on a really old question is low priority, just flag it as "other" and explain it in the text box provided.  Most of us tend to look at the "other" category last.

Comment: [... and you've also all realised that the `close question`'s take the longest, so they never get processed ;).](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PTuJO.png)

Comment: @Matt If that's the view from the 10K queue, I'm not sure if any diamond moderators look in there at all.  If flags sit there long enough they'll eventually be transferred to our queue though.