# Is this a pattern of "Lazy Moderation"?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

If even there is anything like ["Lazy Moderation"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) this sure is not rightly worded by myself. But why are so many of these flags I do on obvious VLQ QA accepted as helpful? I also need to ask the other way round: Why are so few declined?

I run over this: I get for many of the flags I raise on VLQ questions a helpful status and therefore for only some little amount of those flags a declined status. Just for a very little fraction of the VLQ QA I flag, as written to the largest extend I get *helpful* in this domain.

This is done with the following arguments given (I guess these are the standard ones so probably not much news for everybody). Please note that for *helpful* there is no argument given. That is why I can only present one argument here:

> *declined* - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

My EI is flagging me that this overall pattern it spots might be "lazy moderation" so giving me a warn-sign under the hood that something might gone out of order for all of my flagging.

Some thoughts do poke me: *"Shouldn't moderators less often (or the opposite depending on the point-of-view) confirm a flag with* helpful *when problematic material on site is pointed to them that could be dealt with anyway by users doing delete-votes?"*

As written, this is subtle. The difference can only be manifested on a small fraction of all flags and only by the difference between those two different responses. It looks to me that this happens at some little time-spans only (as I just saw when I reviewed my flags) - things like *"probably one moderator that thinks differently across the board?"* pop into mind. But I can hardly imagine that this is the case, because  wouldn't that just be "*lazy moderation*" then (by that one *or* all the others depending on the point-of-view)? But moderation can never be lazy - it is as documented: necessary and as little as possible.

As this implies that this should not happen at all (naturally substracting the standard variance things have first), does it mean that I should better stop to flag obvious VLQ material because something is not right with flagging such per-se? E.g. has the overall amount of VLQ material on site gone out of control and the moderator queue is getting flooded by users flagging obvious [VLQ questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/147909)?

> ***Samples:***
>
> the first two are an example of such a batch of declined flags with the named argument, the rest are those from the same-question-review in the same line-up that are not (and continuing but I started from the back. But this already shows quite well the weight and hopefully makes more visible what I ask about)

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857502/deploy-several-server-side-technologies-on-the-same-server
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832367/my-codes-get-data-from-mux-jsonlock-net
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805071/how-to-upload-a-video-using-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721945/fetching-the-video-from-any-url-using-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789117/i-want-to-get-count-of-results-from-googlephp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867414/put-a-variable-in-bottom-of-all-pages-when-printing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773223/php-most-meaningful-word
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698320/check-if-data-already-there-into-a-db-when-loaded-the-page-with-ajax-and-jquery
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139495/store-every-new-new-email-in-database
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908592/attendance-management-system-in-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019781/facebook-login-button-api-how-to-do-it
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012517/simple-quiz-test-using-php-script-is-not-working
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997239/how-to-decrypt-encrypted-php-source-code
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922778/how-to-stream-live-on-website
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922259/how-air-reservation-system-work-in-server-of-airlines
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715021/php-and-mysql-playlist
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999175/questioners-coding-in-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973667/attendance-system-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940083/how-to-implementation-scrypt-in-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876548/example-php-web-service-client-to-connect-to-the-android-app-emulator-and-a
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879760/someone-give-me-an-example-of-a-client-web-service-that-uses-soap-and-json-forma
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830771/help-convert-user-js-to-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773018/can-someone-check-the-code-of-my-page-please
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763850/change-php-code-to-c-sharp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863334/how-to-get-checked-on-first
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740334/build-sql-statement-on-here
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737110/code-igniter-vs-other-php-frameworks
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962394/desktop-application-programming

Comment: What are the example of declined flags?

Comment: Given the size of SO, mods could be just too busy to deal with VLQ. You can edit or downvote them. Leave the mods for important stuff like spam and voting violations.

Comment: I mean the examples of answers/questions that you flagged, and got the flag declined.

Comment: @Antony: VLQ is a flag-reason given by the tools. I think for the busy-level there is a queue so they can leave flags if they are too busy.

Comment: @nhahtdh: That are questions that got closed, downvoted and having no answers at all and those then hand picked-reviewed by myself to not contain any userful material.

Comment: As long as the question is written in English, and it is readable, and somewhat state the problem, (and not promotional or offensive), then VLQ flag does not apply.

Comment: This is the official one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous

Comment: So you flag *already closed questions* as VLQ?

Comment: @JonW: Why not? Not that I think they would ever be re-opened, but if it's of uttermost low-quality there is no reason to keep them.

Comment: Because you just add work to the mod queue - I would reject as well!

Comment: @hakre Because those do not need moderator intervention. They'll be deleted automatically.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin': Says who? From the moderator feedback I get through the system, this is speaking a different langauge (a very different language). That is why I ask.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin': So now you swapped arguments? In a matter of seconds.... .

Comment: @hakre Says Brad Larson, below, says common sense. If they're deleted automatically, why bother a moderator with them - unless of course there's something egregiously wrong with them that may require immediate intervention.

Comment: @hakre I didn't change the argument, I added an explanation why they don't require moderator intervention.

Comment: Sorry, but as I just wrote, for the majority of these flags, I get a positive response. Which signals me, that I should continue with that. On the other hand I get a small fraction which says "your business". I can live with each of those repsonses on it's very own, however I do not get them together in the overall picture. So I ask myself how does that go together, what *does* need moderator attention?

Comment: @hakre Generally, flags raised with good intentions aren't declined, even if unnecessary. So you flag low quality closed questions that will be auto-deleted. Good intention, but superfluous, mods usually dismiss as helpful. Hypothesis: Some moderator notices you do that a lot. Wants to send you the message "stop flagging these, they're dealt with automatically". A custom decline message would have been better for that. Different hypothesis: most moderators say "Good intentions, okay", one or two say "Don't bother us with that - decline". Anyway, for the future, you should now be aware that ...

Comment: ... flagging closed unanswered low-quality questions is unnecessary, and you can choose between flagging on and getting some declined, or not flagging those (unless immediate intervention is necessary, but then use "other").

Comment: The *actual* lazy behavior is when we mark a ton of VLQ flags as helpful because it's easier than clicking through the menu to reject. That happens more than I'd like to admit. (edit: just did it on this very question, although in my defense, it was a Community ♦ flag.)

Comment: Note the dupe is the official response (and note, our actions on those flags impact the review queues, so it's important that we reject these).  VLQ is supposed to be for those things which are *truly* indecipherable (where you say "WTF").  Most of the links you've posted aren't indecipherable, they're just *really* crappy questions.

Comment: @mmyers: This sure goes in both directions, flagging so many helpful when the flags aren't could also be a sign that somebody is lazy. This is not a moral question why I post, I want to learn more about this that is why I ask. Seems like I found a good topic for that, albeit it seems, the way I framed this up, I get the downvotes ;)

Comment: @casperOne: Just checked the dupe. I also see the answer is much older. However, it is totally different to what my experience is. Can you explain (I can see the duplicate character, but this is not answered there, or is it just a big yes?) how this goes together?

Comment: @hakre Basically, the review queues are fed with what we accept/decline in the spam, not an answer, and VLQ flags.  If we don't accept and decline them literally, then the review queues will be populated with items that aren't what they say they are (these items are used as honeypot posts to capture people who are being lazy in the review queue).

Comment: @casperOne: So manually flagging VLQ is helping the reviewqueue then or not? Just want to know.

Comment: If the flag is marked as helpful, then yes, it helps the review queues.  If it's not marked as helpful, then it doesn't help anything.

Comment: The phrase is "quote, unquote"

Comment: @casperOne: Thanks, good to know. I try to improve even further, I only got very little declines compared to the helpful ones. I also re-worded this question a little because some users told me it might be borderline unsulting.

Comment: @random: I prefer this variant to make visible that it's not my native language.

Comment: @random: I didn't get your last comment on the now deleted answer. The "Just because and not because" part sounded contradictory to me. So you think the "lazyness" is with the moderators that confirm the VLQ as helpful or not?

Comment: Why do you hate us so much that you want to waste our precious time?  Tell me which moderator touched you, and show me on the doll where.

Comment: The phrase "quote, unquote" is not necessary in writing. You just put quotes around the phrase you're quoting.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: A stylistic device, which on the other hand is a good example why code is not poetry.

Comment: @Won't: Deal with it ;)

Comment: @random: Can you elaborate what you mean [by](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently#comment539563_178681) *"Mods who dismiss as helpful just because and not because the flag matches the eventual outcome are being lazy. That is all."*? Does it mean, mods do accept as helpful because they have no other choice, not because the moderator thinks the flag was actually helpful?

Comment: @random ♦ because "The Aliens..." quote-unquote

Answer (score 21):

I can't comment on the specific motivations for the moderators who declined your flags, but you've been going through and flagging a bunch of downvoted, unanswered, and already-closed questions as "very low quality." These are three recent questions which had declined "low quality" flags on them:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915767/php-fetch-table
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915377/display-result-by-mathing-all-input-not-only-one
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981638/libphp-backend-function-for-lua-pascal-realbasic-c-qt-on-mac-os-x

There really isn't a good reason to flag these for moderator attention, because [the automatic deletion system will take care of them for us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) (in fact, [it is about to do so for us sooner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/135615)). There isn't an urgent need for us to step in to remove those right now, which is a likely reason why some of your flags were declined.

Comment: Oh, VLQ on closed, downvoted questions?  Yeah, no point in that.  When flagging something, you should be able to identify some action that the person handling the flag could reasonably take in response.  If the response is just "yeah, so?", then the flag won't accomplish anything except creating some work for the person handling it.

Comment: @Monica Cellio: There is use in rating a question I suppose. I gave my rating with the flag and a moderator then confirms or declines that rating. For me it is not given at all that this on it's own is a useless process as you write. Why should it? Other mods also write that this data is actually used to make this website better.

Answer (score 6):

If you're flagging already closed questions as VLQ then I'm surprised you haven't had more flags declined, to be honest.

The purpose of flagging is so moderators can handle bad questions. If they've already been closed then they've already *been* handled.

The questions that are closed are done so primarily for the poster to then improve the question so it can possibly be reopened. If you're flagging closed questions then you are expecting these questions to be deleted? That doesn't give the OP a chance to improve it. It doesn't matter if a low quality question sits there closed for ages; nobody can answer it so it's not like it's harming the site. If anything it shows people the such questions aren't suitable on the site.

If the OP doesn't improve it then it'll be deleted automatically, if they do improve it then it will be added to the reopen queue so other site users can vote on whether or not it is good enough to reopen. Neither of these options require moderator intervention.

Comment: Thanks for making a difference. The point you raise in the very first sentence is actually the interesting one. What follows does not explain why it's not so. As every question, we can word it in both ways: Why are so many of these flags accepted as helpful?

Comment: I don't know why either. I am a mod on another stackexchange site http://ux.stackexchange.com/ and I would, and indeed have, rejected flags when they've been raised on already closed questions.

Comment: So from your moderators perspective would you say: I would not count at all, so regardless which response is given (helpful, not needed etc.) isn't important at all, just giving any is the key to get the flag removed from the queue?

Comment: Perhaps those mods were just being nice and not just rejecting outright. The default response for mods when dealing with flags is 'if in doubt as to whether it's a valid flag or not then mark it as helpful'. A mod has to do *something* with the flag otherwise it stays there. We either accept it or reject it.

Comment: That is one option I had in mind, too, however according to the now linked duplicate this is not the case. I've even learned the duplicate is an FAQ question which says that now this is handled strictly so what you suggest *should* not be the case. There probably is a difference between SO here and the other sites about the moderation guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Without specific examples it's hard to say what's going on in your case, but the Stack Exchange engine *has* built-in responses, so why would you not expect moderators to use them?  Your flag was *declined*, therefore not helpful, so why should mods be thankful that you raised them?  *Do* keep flagging, but don't expect every flag to be valuable and try not to get upset when some of them are declined.

Also make sure you're using "very low quality" correctly.  It's for things like link-only answers, non-answer comments, etc.  It's not for "this is just wrong"; for issues of quality, use votes and comments.  If you flag something you could have addressed through other means, that flag will almost certainly be declined.

Comment: As written, VLQ flags on these questions are largely accepted as helpful (and deleted). What I put here on meta is about the rel. very small fraction where I get the declines which seems to come in these small batches. I will compile a list of questions that were deemed helpful and also some of these declines to make this more transparent.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a handful of moderators on each site, and yet there are many, many regular users.  There is way too many moderation actions that need to be taken for them to be handled entirely by the mods.  The site was designed such that it could be primarily community moderated.

There are a handful of actions that simply can't be properly handled by regular users.  It's not a lot, but it is some.  This is precisely what flagging is for.  It's for those problems that you simply can't handle on your own, or can't be handled by other non-moderator users.\

It's not a matter of being lazy.  There simply aren't enough moderators for them to handle the workload if everyone just flags content that they're capable of handling on their own.

Comment: I am quite sure most of the case of VLQ flag declined is because the flag is on a post that is readable (ignoring the fact whether it has good quality or not) and not plain garbage.