# Edited PostLowQualityAuto still get a downvote

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts

Per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/160923) from Jeff, the Very Low Quality flag:

> 1. The VLQ flag now carries a downvote from community. It is like "spam flag lite", meaning, no reputation penalty but like spam, it
>      incurs a downvote from the community user.
> 2. If a post is edited, any pending VLQ flags are now cleared (without harm) from the post. It is unclear that a post is still VLQ if it has
>      been edited since it was flagged.

I am not sure if #2 is applying to PostLowQualityAuto flags.  I was able to reproduce this by

- Clicking on the link in the flag listing.
- Editing the post (in my case it was an answer, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/78282).
- Dismissing the flag as helpful

When I dismissed the flag, the score remained at 0, but when I refreshed the page, it went down to -1.

Comment: If I'm reading that right, the flag should've been dismissed by the edit; if that doesn't happen, then your dismissal is the only one that would've applied.

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, I am kinda confused.  I think this may have started within the last few weeks.