# Flag with wrote down reason only

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

Currently I can review low quality posts. I got a lot of flags, but rarely explanation about the problem, so I have to investigate every case, which is sometimes fast, and sometimes not really. It would made things easier if I could read something about why the actual post was flagged? (Is this because I have not enough points, or nobody can see this information?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no additional information to be seen as the system is currently designed. Questions end up in the `Low Quality Posts` queue due to "length and content", which either happens automatically in the case of very short posts, or manually when a user flags it as `it is very low quality`. As [Jeff Atwood once said of this flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/246931), "It is a call for a pooper-scooper." As such, it really shouldn't be unclear why the flag is there, **if it is valid**. If it isn't, hit <kbd>Looks good</kbd> and move along, or <kbd>Edit</kbd> if you see room for improvement.

I don't see any need to add more options or inputs for flaggers here; other options exist and should usually be preferred when it's not plainly obvious that a post needs to be removed. If you have a particular idea in mind of additional info that would be useful, you might consider editing your feature request to be more specific. Otherwise maybe you'd prefer to ask a discussion question on Meta Stack Overflow regarding whether this flag is being raised appropriately in the community.

Comment: Just a few examples: I got an answer which was the copy of another, but before opening the question I did not realize this. Ppl in hurry probably would not open the question and they would have rejected the flag. Other example when sy sent a short answer to his own question, which did not seem to be low quality to me. And these are only the first ones in a very long row...

Comment: If you could link to the specific examples among [those you've reviewed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/607033/inf3rno?tab=activity&sort=reviews), that would help. Sounds like whoever flagged should've commented about the duplicate answer on the first one, and sounds like "looks good" is the appropriate response to the second, at least from your perspective.

Comment: Okay, next time I have a concrete problem I will create ask a new meta question. (If I'll have enough points to do that. :D)

Comment: @inf3rno: don't worry about points as far as that goes; there's no rep requirement. Just be careful not to get too many questions closed or deleted! That can result in a temporary suspension of asking privileges (the first one is usually pretty short – like a week, as far as I've seen). Of course, during that suspension you can still look around for other questions that might tell you what you want to know.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep in mind that.

Comment: Not an Answer flags now [also feed in to the low quality review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/209637) (it is not just automatic based on length and content anymore).

Comment: Ooh...Didn't know that! That could make things somewhat trickier. Maybe important to use "skip" once in a while too!