# Who downvotes a post when we flag a post a spam?

Tags: support, flags, voting, spam

Recently I reviewed a [post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6690/467) on the Hinduism site and found that it is actually spam. When I flag it as spam, it showed a -1 vote to the post. This usually happens whenever you flag a post as spam, it gets -1 vote (one vote down).

At first I thought that -1 vote might be given by [Community ♦](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), but if the same post is flagged as spam by another user then one more -1 vote is added to the post (-2 votes) and, according to voting rules, the same user cannot perform the same vote cast for the same post (i.e., a single user can not upvote/downvote a post twice/multiple times).

So who actually gives -1 vote to this post?

Comment: Flagging as spam has nothing to do with Downvotes. Some users use downvotes to demonstrate the spam others use the "flag as spam" option

Comment: @Jehof No, flagging as spam auto-downvotes the post.

Comment: I think it is Community. That account has a lot of privileges that regular user accounts don't have.

Comment: @user4098326. you are right. Each flag carries an implicit downvote for calculating the post's score (it does not affect the caster's reputation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's absolutely the Community user that owns the auto-downvotes. The normal rule for multiple-voting simply doesn't apply to Community. It gets to cheat the rules like that, since it's not really a normal user (See also, e.g., its having 1 reputation no matter what, its negative user ID, etc.).

Comment: Your answer is correct: _The reason why it has so many downvotes is because it owns all of the downvotes that are being cast automatically when you flag a post as spam or offensive._

Comment: @Jehof plus votes of very active users (with thousands of votes) who ask to delete their account, so the team preserve their voting by transferring to Community account. :)

Comment: All that, and also it [auto-downvotes any post with a helpful VLQ flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/226203). Oh, and once upon a time, it auto-downvoted closed questions sometimes, mostly depending on close reason, I think. Community is overall a very negative user.